# Who holds the rights to the rebooted universe (Abrams) in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

What company(ies) holds the rights to the universe in Star Trek (2009) and Star Trek Into Darkness (2013)? Just to clarify, I'm looking for either CBS or Paramount Pictures; the readings on Wikipedia and articles sometimes contradict each other.

This question is intended to find out whether CBS have the rights to set a new Star Trek TV show in the rebooted universe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a grey area and one frequently battled over. Paramount holds the rights to all movie distributions. CBS has primary rights on the TV shows, but Paramount partners with them on distribution of the TV series. Further, Paramount must license the actual Star Trek characters from CBS to be used in the films and for all merchandising.

There's a good discussion [over here](https://www.thewrap.com/how-web-star-trek-rights-killed-jj-abrams-grand-ambitions-91766/) that talks about this constant ongoing battle being on of the primary drivers for JJ Abrams leaving Star Trek to take on the Star Wars movies.